# Android delete SMS notifications out of my app

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I have written a little alternative SMS App. It shows me the received SMS. So I want to delete SMS notifications if the user read the SMS in my App. But how can I do this ? I just found out how to remove notifications of the own application, so this doesn't work  for my problem. 
I set the read value from unread to read. But the notifications doesn't disappear.

`ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
 cv.put("read", 1);
 this.getContentResolver().update(insms, cv, "address = ? OR address = ?", new String[]{nummer, k.getNummer()});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete the system's SMS notifications.
You can, however, create your own notifications on SMS receiving, and delete them as the user interacts with them.